# How to find the input element in my html markup

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to use regular expression to find if the variable contains an input field.

My html in my variable could be something like this.

```
<span>test here</span>
```

or

```
 <span><input type="text"></span>
```

My codes are like

```
//$(this) is be my variable

if($(this).html().match("/<input type='text'>/")){
          console.log('match found')
 }
```

It doesn't seem to be able to find the match. Can anyone help me about it? thanks a lot!

Comment: An `input` element should *never* have a closing `</input>` tag, it's a self-closing element, and should be written `<input />`. Incidentally is your variable a *string* of HTML, or an actual DOM node wrapped in a jQuery object?

Comment: probably just a typo in your question, but you have tyep="text", is it also like that in your actual html / non-dom stuff?

Comment: Looks like you fixed it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
if ($(this).find('input[type="text"]').length) {
    console.log('match found');
}
```

If `this` is a string of HTML text (as indicated), you can still use the same code, for example

```
$('<span>test here</span>').find('input').length // equals 0

$('<span><input tyep="text"></span>').find('input').length // equals 1
```

Comment: Yeah I think he maybe wanting to match inputs that aren't in the dom or mark-up - just string?

Comment: yes I need to match the input that is not in the dom. just plan html text. +1 though

Comment: You can't have HTML that isn't part of the DOM. In any case, wrapping a string of HTML text in `$()` as you're doing with `$(this)` will convert it to a jQuery object containing DOM elements

Comment: Addendum to my comment above; You can't have HTML that isn't part of the DOM *unless you're strictly talking about a JavaScript string*

Answer (score 1):

I'm not precisely sure what you are trying to do, but I beleive this will get the same result as the above `$(this).find('input[type="text"]')`

If you are looking for a regex `/input\s+[^>]*type\s*=\s*['"]text['"]/` should do the trick.

Comment: good one but I am not match the dom. it's html plain text. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're after a regular expression for the input tag, this could be a basic one:

```
<input .*type=['"]text['"].*/>
```

this will match any input tag with type="text" (double or single quotes) and any attributes in between.

If the input elements are already on the page, I would suggest jQuery:

```
if($('input[type=text]').length > 0){
   console.log('match found');
}
```

**Please note** the input element does **not** require a closing tag

`<input type="text"></input>` but rather `<input type="text" />`